# C Reading words from text file

Tags: c, file, hash, io

I'm writing a simple function that takes as input 3 already opened FILES's, then scans through each character in the file, filling up a char array until a ' ' whitespace is reached or a newline is found.  However, my method of filling an array keeps giving me a `Segmentation fault` and I'm not really sure why.  For now I am just attempting to print to console the words that were filled in the word[] array, then clearing it with memset for the next word.

```
hash_table_t training(FILE *D1, FILE *D2, FILE *D3, int size)
{

char *word[200];
char c;
int i = 0;

while ((c = fgetc(D1)) != EOF)
{
    while (((c>='a') && (c<='z')) || ((c>='A') && (c<='Z')))
    {
        //add to char array
        *word[i++] = c;
    }
    if(c == ' ' || c=='\n')
    {
        //hash word (print chars for now)
        for (i=0; *word[i] != ' '; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", *word[i]);
        }

    }
    memset (word, ' ', 20);

}

fclose(D1);
fclose(D2);
fclose(D3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `word`array is a array of pointer, not a array of character.
You should change

```
char* word[200];
```

to

```
char word[200];
```

and

```
*word[i];
```

to

```
word[i];
```

Comment: You'll need to change the use of `word` elsewhere, too.

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks for the reminder.  Post too fast.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `word` as an array of character *pointers*, assign them *characters*, and try to dereference those values.

Answer (score -1):

The variable "word" as you have declared it is not a char array/cstring, but it is a pointer to a string with a size of 200; this would work but you have not initialized the string with "malloc" hence the "Segmentation Fault" error as you are trying to change a part of memory not allocated to your program.

Edit: Also, as a tip, always initialize pointers as soon as creation; because they are pointing to random parts of memory upon creation, the code may not always give you a "Segmentation Fault" error, because it may point to a part of memory that IS allocated to your program.
Worst case, you will have  a really hard-to-track bug.

Comment: How, then, would you declare an array of 200 pointers to characters?

Comment: The declaring isn't the problem, the problem is that you haven't initialized them:
char* word[200] = malloc (200*sizeof(char)) ;

Comment: @Arce  `char *word[200]` is an array of 200 `char *`... a pointer to an array of 200 `char` would be `char (*word)[200]`